# Changes are made only if I debug trough the code line by line

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have multiple mini-SPAs in Angular JS that live inside MVC views, and I make API calls to handle the requests.

The problem I am having is rather strange. I post an object that looks something like this:

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Param1 { get; set; }

    public Guid? Param2 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Param3{ get; set; }

    ...

}
```

The `Param2` property is a nullable guid that I fill up from a select HTML element and it's a guid from an object which is in a `one to zero or one` relationship with the object I'm editing.

The code in the controller that handles that property looks like this:

```
item.SubItem = await _db.SubItems.FindAsync(model.Param2);
```

If `Param2` is null, then the result is null and everything is OK, but not quite so.

If I run the app, hit a breakpoint and go trough the code lines one row at a time, the `SubItem` is set to null and everything is OK, but if I run the app without debugging, all the other properties get changed, but the `SubItem` property isn't set to null.

This problem only occurs if I want to set `SubItem` to null, if I want to change it's value to anything else, it works fine.

**EDIT:**
 Also, this has the same effect:

```
if (model.Param2 == null)
{
    item.SubItem = null;
}
else
{
    item.SubItem = _db.SubItems.Find(model.Param2);
}
```

Comment: Dr. House, have you checked what happens if you remove the `async/await` piece of this? I would take some of the intricacies of that out of the equation. Chances are you don't really need it anyway.

Comment: Have a look at my edit, I tried that as well, but still the same

Comment: param3 is not a nullable guid. "public DateTime Param3{ get; set; }"

Comment: My bad, I was talking about Param2, I'll edit the mistakes

Comment: Did you try to use model.Param2.HasValue() instead of == null ? (just guessing here)

Comment: The logic is good, it all works, but only works if I set a breakpoint and go line by line with F10, if I run it without debugging it doesn't change that value